# orderby in linq only when column is not null using lambda

Tags: linq

Please let me know how can I can use orderby in linq only when a particular column is not `null` using lambda expression:

```
var list=  // result returned from sql stored proc 

list.orderby(s=>s.empid!=null).select(p=>p) //something like this
```

Is it possible to include a condition to perform orderby on the list?

Comment: People are unlikely to answer your questions when you never accept answers.

Comment: If you had proper capitalization on the method names, then it would probably work... what are you expecting?

Comment: jeff i know the method list.orderby(s=>s.empid!=null) ie orderby is wrong please see my comments ie "something like this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = _context.Products
                       .Where(p => p.EmpId != null)
                       .OrderBy(p => p.EmpId)
                       .Select(p => p)
```

Comment: The last `Select` call seems unnecessary. Can you tell me why you used it?

Comment: Was basing my answer from the OP's code as it is, I assumed he used `.Select()` to cast into new type (without the properties).